# What is a good way to catch the Mysterious Stranger?

Tags: fallout-shelter

When ever I hear the music to indicate the Mysterious Stranger has arrived, I can never find him. It is almost like he is not in the vault.

What is a good way to catch the Mysterious Stranger? Where does he usually show up?

Comment: I've caught him in any room, and also saw him disappear into an elevator once.

Answer (score 6):

He shows up in random places, so there is no place he usually shows up.

One hint is the volume of the music. If the music is louder, he's closer to where you're currently looking. Wearing headphones helps to determine how loud it is.

Answer (score 3):

**Have Less Rooms**

As the Mysterious Stranger can appear in *any room*, you'll increase your chances of spotting him if you decrease the number of places he can spawn. Get rid of excess items and decrease your storage rooms (because you don't *really* need 100 things of Yarn or those 18 .32's), upgrade your rooms to max so you can run less off them, make your Vault as compact as possible to also get rid of elevators.

**Use Color-Clashing Rooms**

With the new feature of theme rooms, choose themes for your rooms that are not brownish, so that when he does show up, he will be easier to spot.

**Give All Your Dwellers Highly Visible Outfits**

Just how it's harder to spot him in a brown room, it will be harder to spot him when all your dwellers are wearing trenchcoats.

**Get A Pet**

A specific type of tiger-striped cat will increase the chance of him spawning.  I have a cat named *Kato* that gives a 7.5x bonus to spawns!

**Take Screenshots**

As @psycho brm has stated, take a screenshot once you know he's there, and play a little game of Where's the Mysterious Stranger before opening up the app again and spotting him.

**Other "Strageties"**

I'm of the mindset that he usually spawns *just outside* of the visible space you are currently looking at in-game, but for every time I think I can confirm this hypothesis, there are 2 or more times when this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Make a screenshot (with HD zoom out disabled), switch to photos application to find him, then come back to get him.

Turn on vibration in settings and you can do this everytime the phone vibrates, while watching movie or something...

Answer (score 0):

One tactic that helps is to play on a large screen device but fully-zoomed out with "HD graphics zoomed out" turned off.

The trickiest part of the Mysterious Strange is that he can appear behind objects.  In a level 3 Medical Center, he can appear in that tiny room in the back.

By zooming out all the way and the game switching to flat sprites, there is nothing for him to hide behind and it'll be a little easier to find him.

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution to catch the Mysterious Stranger is wearing Headphones, as the music which plays once he appears comes from his exact place, and you can find him by moving the camera and get the music to the center of the screen, using arrow keys or AWSD makes it easier to move the camera
I can tell that i catch him at least 50% of times he appears